# CSS @font-face is not working propertly

Tags: css, font-face

My website font is showing differently in my laptop. It's ok On my PC (Desktop.) To solve this issue I'm trying to use following CSS code:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;    
    background-color:#f4f4f4;    
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:25px;   
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
    src: url('font/MyriadPro-Bold.OTF') format('OTF'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
        url('font/MyriadPro-Bold.OTF') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
    src: url('font/MyriadPro-Bold.OTF') format('OTF'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
        url('font/MyriadPro-Bold.OTF') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

But still it's showing different font style in my Laptop. Why?

Comment: What is the difference ? Which OS is each one ? Which browser is each one ?

Comment: Does this also happen on other browsers you use on your respepective PCs?

Comment: can you download the file manually? Is the browser using the right path when downloading the fonts in the Network tab of developer tools/firebug/web inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling a custom font on your project; Make sure that font is uploaded on server where your project files are uploaded.

You will required a each format font type like `(.eot, .woff, and ttf)`

> /*-----------------TTF to EOT Font Converter--------------------*/

http://ttf2eot.sebastiankippe.com/

```
body {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro', Fallback, sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  src: url('MyriadPro-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('MyriadPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('MyriadPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('MyriadPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('MyriadPro-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these solutions.

1. Ensure that your src Font folders are resolving in you laptop (you could use developer tools on almost any browser(press F12 Key), click Network tab and see if there are any resource not loading properly)
2. If your site is running on IIS sometimes you must register the Mime Types in web.config with the following settings

(This worked Fine for me because i'm using IIS 7.0)

1. Try adding more Font files, sometimes old browsers do not recognize the fonts in the proper way.
   I'll recommend you to try this page http://everythingfonts.com/font-face it will get you the whole Font-face markup and the fonts needed in each format(eot,woff,svg and ttf). I use it when i need to add a Font-face and Works great.